# Calling a C program from a Python program

Tags: python-3.x

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   return "hello, world";
}
```

The above C code has been compiled in a program called hello.c

I would like to call the above C program from a Python program in order to print the return message "hello, world".

Is there a simple Python code example to do this? Something like this:
    import hello.c
    print(return)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python

Comment: You got the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html

Comment: Also it should be noted, an application's entry point must return a status code, not a string pointer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)